# mapping elements from array in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-sea-yq1uu)

I have following scenario. I am counting all my skill names char length and if that length is greater then 25 I am hiding all rest skills and showing in number how many skills is hided. That part is now working. But when I can't show my visible skills. Can you help me to resolve that problem and optimized my code if you think there is something wrong.

Thank you.

here my skills

```
    const skills = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Html"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "css"
      },
 
   ... and so on
];
```

my code part:

```
   let lengthCount = 0;
   let maxIndex = 0;
   const skill = [];

   const Skill = () => {
    skills.map((item, index) => {
      if (lengthCount <= 20) {
        maxIndex = index;
        skill.push(item.name); // I am adding items to my skill array
       }
     lengthCount = lengthCount + item.name.length;
    });

    // mapping items from skill array
    let mySkills = skill.map((perSkill) => (
      <span key={perSkill.id} className="element">
        {perSkill.name}
      </span>
     ));
    
    
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div>{mySkills}</div>+{skills.length - maxIndex - 1}
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing `item.name` in your `skill` array. So the array will only contain names and not objects. So print perSkill, and not `perSkill.name`. If you want `skill` to be an array of objects, then use:

`skill.push(item)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `{perSkill.name}` to `{perSkill}` and it'll work fine

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-microservice-hecf3?file=/src/components/Skill.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

I use reduce to loop through you skills, and each step we update object { total, list} if the total + new name length > LIMIT_NUMBER we just return the old one. If not we append new item to the object.list and increase the total.

```js
const LIMIT_NUMBER = 5
const skills = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Html"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "css"
      }]
      
const newSkillList = skills.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if (acc.total + curr.name.length > LIMIT_NUMBER){
      return acc
   } else{
      const total = acc.total + curr.name.length
      const list = [...acc.list, curr]
      return {list, total}
   }
},{list:[], total: 0})
console.log(newSkillList)
```